# Microsoft trying to patent hyperlocal data

Tags: prior-art-request, us20130031458

Seeking Prior Art Submission for 2013-0031458 A1

This application tries to patent pretty much hyperlocal content delivery by merely stating details of common clustering techniques used with user geolocation data. It appears to be Bing Local Search

Here are some claims in question:

Claim 1:
A system comprising
-a reference acquisition component that obtains a first indicator associated with a first web page document 
-a classification type component that determines a classification type of the first web page document, based on the first indicator and a first content of the first web page document;
-an attention geography component that determines a group of first attention geography items associated with the first web page document ;
-a content geography component that determines a group of first content geography items associated with the first web page document; 
-and a hyperlocal classifier that determines, via a device processor, whether the first web page document includes a first hyperlocal content page document, based on the group of the first attention geography items and the group of the first content geography items.

Claim 6:
The system of claim 1, further comprising: a posting crawler component that obtains a plurality of first posted items associated with the first web page document, based on initiating a plurality of first web page retrieval visits to the first web page document
-and a posting locale determination component that determines a first locale associated with the plurality of first posted items based on geographic attributes associated with the obtained plurality of first posted items associated with the first web page document. ;

Claim 7:
The system of claim 6, further comprising: a document transformation component that updates a first annotated document item associated with the first web page document via annotations based on the obtained plurality of first posted items associated with the first web page document.

Claim 8:
The system of claim 7, further comprising: an ngram component that obtains tokens based on text included in the plurality of first posted items associated with the first web page document, and determines ranking values of obtained tokens based on term frequency values and document frequency values.

Essentially, we're talking about things like Yelp, but I believe Yelp has joined with Microsoft for this product.

We need to beat July 27, 2011

My guess is that there are Google results that are delivered like this, that utilize well-known clustering techniques and user geolocation- but a technical document specifying that can be hard to find.

Comment: https://www.google.com/patents/US20130031458?dq=2013-0031458+A1&hl=en&sa=X&ei=508MUs2VLoPB4AOW_4C4Aw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA

user5341, those kinds of terms mean nothing. The entire language is meant to confuse. It essentially just means a processing unit.

Comment: Speaking of confusing language. My wife is responsible for drafting patent documents for her employers. The language she originally writes in is clear, journal/magazine style language that any engineer can understand. Then it goes to the lawyers and when it comes back it's been transformed to patent-speak.

Answer (score 1):

So a software program running on a computer that searches through web pages (but only the FIRST web page) and organizes it based on location keywords?

IE: searching for "fire 1871" when I'm in Chicago.

Google has been doing this for a while now.

[news clip, 2009](http://www.newsfactor.com/story.xhtml?story_id=65814)

Answer (score 0):

Please share the link to the original patent text. I have no clue what a "reference acquisition component" is. I am sorry that you have to read this and make sense out of it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/patents/US20130031458?dq=2013-0031458+A1&hl=en&sa=X&ei=508MUs2VLoPB4AOW_4C4Aw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA

user5341, those kinds of terms mean nothing. The entire language is meant to confuse. It essentially just means a processing unit that determines some reference (any reference at all). Welcome to the world of vague patents.

In general, the needed art includes geolocating user visits, etc to a webpage from mobile devices, etc. Those geolocated points are input into a clustering algorithm to determine visitation patterns for businesses and their web pages in nearby areas, etc.